# ul li text not perfect vertically aligned with checkbox

Tags: css

Inside `<li>` the checkbox is perfectly in the middle by default but the text after the checkbox insists on going to the bottom. How can I vertically and perfectly align the text inside the `<li>` with the checkbox in the middle?

[Here's the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HywAC.jpg)

I've already tried `vertical-align: middle` but the text stays in the bottom as well.

```css
div.CheckBoxList_1 {
  font-size: 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="CheckBoxList_1">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_1" checked />TEXT_1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_2" checked />TEXT_2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_3" checked />TEXT_3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_4" checked />TEXT_4</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_5" checked />TEXT_5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `input { vertical-align: middle; }` …?

Comment: When insert the code in the "question" form, he says to use backsticks (`) as TAB . But in fact the code never be format properly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` in your `div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li` CSS. Resolve your issue. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: super;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```css
div.CheckBoxList_1 {
  font-size: 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="CheckBoxList_1">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_1" checked />TEXT_1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_2" checked />TEXT_2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_3" checked />TEXT_3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_4" checked />TEXT_4</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxArray[]" value="TEXT_5" checked />TEXT_5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `input`, not the `li`.

Set your `vertical-align: middle;` on the `<input>`.

```css
div.CheckBoxList_1 {
  font-size: 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="CheckBoxList_1">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />TEXT_1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />TEXT_2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />TEXT_3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />TEXT_4</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />TEXT_5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your css with my css

```
div.CheckBoxList_1 {
  font-size: 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  /*display: none;*/
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}

div.CheckBoxList_1 ul li {
     border: 1px solid #0000ff4a;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why for a better answer

Comment: Ok @SuperDJ next time I will take care of it, thanks

Comment: This does not work. You need the `vertical-align: middle;` on the `input` element as I added in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to better understand how to use `vertical-align`.  It only aligns text vertically when used in a table cell or another element that has the property `display: table-cell;`  In other uses, it specifies how text should align around the element.  So in your case, you need to add the `vertical-align: middle;` to the input rather than the list item.

In addition, you also need to set the `line-height` of the list item to be equal to the height, which will better center the text vertically.

[See this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kehz04a8/)